# How to let compiler catch inconsistent type of global variables in two source files of C

Tags: c, types, global-variables

my1.c

```
extern float e;
void f1(){ e=3.0;}
```

my2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int e=0;
void f1();
void main(){
  printf("%d in main \n", e);
  f1();
  printf("%d in main \n", e);
}
```

Here the global variable `e` is mistakenly declared as `float` and `int` in two source files.

How to let the linker raise error for this inconsistency?

Comment: Wouldn't that be nice? It wouldn't be difficult to implement, but I've never seen an implementation that even tried.

Comment: Note that if you use a modern version of GCC (10.x or later), you would have a 'doubly-defined variable' error.  One of the two declarations needs `extern` — the one without an initializer.  But that still doesn't do type validation — it doesn't even do size validation (so `double e;` vs `int e;` isn't spotted).

Comment: @zwol Maybe it would not be difficult to implement. You would have to introduce some kind of name mangling for variables, just like C++ does for functions. However using it would be a nightmare. You would not be able to link to libraries compiled with a different compiler and you would lose all ABI backward compatibility.

Comment: @JakobStark One could instead have annotations in a ".note" section of the object file, perhaps using the same format as is used to tell the debugger the types of declarations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We mitigate this risk using header files, not the linker. Anything referred to in multiple translation units should be declared in one header file:

MyGlobal.h:

```
extern float e;
```

Any file that uses it should include the header file:

main.c:

```
#include "MyGlobal.h"

…
    printf("e is %f.\n", e);
```

Exactly one file should define it, and include the header file:

MyGlobal.c:

```
#include "MyGlobal.h"

float e = 0;
```

By using a header file, the declaration is identical in all translation units. Because the source file that defines the identifier also includes the header file, the compiler reports any inconsistency.

Any external declarations (that are not definitions) outside of header files are suspect and should be avoided.

Comment: It seems that C programmers heavily rely on header files and this convention, in checking both variables and functions consistency used in different source files.  I guess that there should also be some preprocessing tools that can check this kind of consistency (e.g., automatically generating functions prototypes, rather than programmers manually providing them)

Comment: @YoujunHu yes C programmers do that. In fact often the header files and the public function and variable declarations contained there are designed before implementing them. This is C's way of providing an abstract interface on top of the actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

1.c

```
static float e;
void f1(){ e=3.0;}
```

2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int e=0;
void f1();
void main()
{
printf("%d in main \n", e);
f1();
printf("%d in main \n", e);
}
```

Comment: In your case, two `e` are different variables in two scopes, which happen to have the same name.